# Discard an email in postfix when the reply-to address is different from that of sender

Tags: postfix, email-server, spam, virtualmin

I've setup virtualmin and the emails are working fine with the Postfix server. However I'd like to add a feature where, in case somebody tries to abuse the server and tries to send an email with a different reply-to address (which is the case in most of email spam) I just want to discard it before being sent.

I've searched in google but couldn't find any. /etc/postfix/header_check is where the configuration I believe.

The server has only two domains and a few email addresses. And the users never abuse it in anyways (And will be in the know that they can't use a different reply-to address).

Thanks for looking into.

Comment: So what is stopping you from using the header_checks approach?

Comment: @anx Thanks for looking into. But I couldn't figure out how to write a condition there.